# Can Flutter's inbuilt Canvas drawing methods be directly used to render variable-width strokes?

Tags: flutter, svg, canvas, flutter-canvas

Can Flutter's inbuilt Canvas drawing methods be directly used to render variable-width strokes, for example to reflect pressure applied throughout each stroke in a handwriting app?

Ideally, in a manner compatible with saving in the XML-esque format of SVG (example at bottom).

---

What I think I've noticed / troubles I'm having / current attempts:

`canvas.drawPath`, `canvas.drawPoints`, `canvas.drawPolygon`, `canvas.drawLines` etc all take only a single Paint object, which can in turn have a single `strokeWidth` (as opposed to taking lists of Paint objects or `strokeWidth`s, such that parameters of the path besides position could change point to point and be interpolated between).

Drawing lines, polygons or points of varying `strokeWidth`s or radii by iterating over lists of position and pressure data and using the respective Canvas method results in no interpolation / paths not looking continuously stroked.

Screenshot from OneNote showing the behaviour I'd like:

[image: variable width lines reflecting input pressure from OneNote]

Screenshot from the app the minimal working example below produces:
[image: variable width, furry lines from my app]

(Unoptimized) minimal working example:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Writeable(),
  ));
}

class Writeable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WriteableState createState() => _WriteableState();
}

class _WriteableState extends State<Writeable> {
  List<List<double>> pressures = List<List<double>>();
  List<Offset> currentLine = List<Offset>();
  List<List<Offset>> lines = List<List<Offset>>();
  List<double> currentLinePressures = List<double>();
  double pressure;
  Offset position;
  Color color = Colors.black;
  Painter painter;
  CustomPaint paintCanvas;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    painter = Painter(
        lines: lines,
        currentLine: currentLine,
        pressures: pressures,
        currentLinePressures: currentLinePressures,
        color: color);

    paintCanvas = CustomPaint(
      painter: painter,
    );

    return Listener(
      onPointerMove: (details) {
        setState(() {
          currentLinePressures.add(details.pressure);
          currentLine.add(details.localPosition);
        });
      },
      onPointerUp: (details) {
        setState(() {
          lines.add(currentLine.toList());
          pressures.add(currentLinePressures.toList());
          currentLine.clear();
          currentLinePressures.clear();
        });
      },
      child: paintCanvas,
    );
  }
}

class Painter extends CustomPainter {
  Painter(
      {@required this.lines,
      @required this.currentLine,
      @required this.color,
      @required this.pressures,
      @required this.currentLinePressures});

  final List<List<Offset>> lines;
  final List<Offset> currentLine;
  final Color color;
  final List<List<double>> pressures;
  final List<double> currentLinePressures;

  double scalePressures = 10;
  Paint paintStyle = Paint();

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  // Paints here using drawPoints and PointMode.lines, but have also tried
  // PointMode.points, PointMode.polygon and drawPath with a path variable and
  // moveTo, lineTo methods.
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Paint line currently being drawn (points added since pointer was
    // last lifted)
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLine.length - 1; i++) {
      paintStyle.strokeWidth = currentLinePressures[i] * scalePressures;
      canvas.drawPoints(
          PointMode.lines, [currentLine[i], currentLine[i + 1]], paintStyle);
    }
    // Paint all completed lines drawn since app start
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].length - 1; j++) {
        paintStyle.strokeWidth = pressures[i][j] * scalePressures;
        canvas.drawPoints(
            PointMode.lines, [lines[i][j], lines[i][j + 1]], paintStyle);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm about to try writing my own implementation for rendering aesthetic SVG-friendly data from PointerEvents, but so many of the existing classes feel SVG/pretty-vectors-compatible (e.g. all the lineTos, moveTos, stroke types and endings and other parameters) that I thought it worth checking if there's something I've missed, and these methods can already do this?

---

Example of a few lines in an SVG file saved by Xournal++, with the stroke-width parameter changing for each line segment, and all other listed parameters presumably also having potential to change. Each line contains a moveTo command (M) and a lineTo command (L), where the latter draws a line from the current position (the last moveTo-ed or lineTo-ed), reminiscent of Flutter's segments/sub-paths and current point, to the specified offset:

```
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.288794;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,100%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;comp-op:src;clip-to-self:true;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 242.683594 45.519531 L 242.980469 45.476562 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.295785;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,100%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;comp-op:src;clip-to-self:true;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 242.980469 45.476562 L 243.28125 45.308594 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.309105;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,100%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;comp-op:src;clip-to-self:true;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 243.28125 45.308594 L 243.601562 45.15625 "/>
```

The approach seems to be 'draw a very short line, change stroke-width, draw the next very short line starting from the previous position', which I've tried to emulate with the paint method above.

Comment: don't use strokeWidth at all, create the outline of each shape and fill it in whatever colour you need. If you want it to appear bolder, create a wider outline.

Comment: @RobertLongson This is what I'm considering doing, but it feels like it would be re-inventing drawPath, so I thought it worth checking this functionality doesn't already exist somewhere. Thanks for the suggestion and validation that it mightn't.

Comment: Nonetheless two things come to my mind that might inspire you: pomax has written an [example function](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/#outline) of how to graduate a bezier curve - the very first step towards drawing calligrafic paths. Inkscape builds outlines from this principle with its freehand drawing tool, which accepts pressure values from tablet devices as input. It's [open source](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/live_effects/lpe-powerstroke.cpp), so you can study how that has been done.

Comment: @RobertLongson My intention was to check if this could be implemented with the libraries I've mentioned, drawPath, drawPoints etc, and my issues were due to misusing them, in the way [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560322/how-to-draw-path-with-variable-width-in-canvas?noredirect=1&lq=1) and several of the related were posed for Android/Java. I see how my phrasing sounded too broad, and I'll try to fix it now.

Comment: @ccprog This looks very useful; thank you!

Comment: You need to set the strokeCap field in the Paint object. You also need to setup multiple buffers if you are accepting drawing inputs in real-time because the CustomPaint widget will repaint ALL the strokes everytime it's updated which probably isn't what you want.